# jquery wrap groups of sub items in divs

Tags: jquery, css

Looking to wrap sub items in their own individual divs.  This is working with older jQuery 1.x- not newer 3.x jQuery.  Attempting to eventually wrap the .group items into accordion style drop downs multiple per page view.

So each grouping of .group would get a div surrounding them.

```js
$(".group").each(function() {
 if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("group")) {
  return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.group)").andSelf();
 }
}).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");
```

```css
.wrap {border: 5px dotted #ff0000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<p class="item group">Item 3</p>
<p class="item group">Item 4</p>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
<p class="item group">Item 6</p>
<p class="item group">Item 7</p>
<p class="item group">Item 8</p>
<p class="item">Item 9</p>
```

Have tried wrap and wrapall to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[`.andSelf()`](https://api.jquery.com/andself/) was removed in jQuery 3.0 You have to use [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

Documentation for àndSelf() clearly mentions it:

> Note: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later.

And it's working again...

```js
$(".group").each(function() {
  if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("group")) {
    return $(this).nextUntil(":not(.group)").addBack();
  }
}).wrap("<div class='wrap' />");
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 5px dotted #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<p class="item group">Item 3</p>
<p class="item group">Item 4</p>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
<p class="item group">Item 6</p>
<p class="item group">Item 7</p>
<p class="item group">Item 8</p>
<p class="item">Item 9</p>
```

---

**EDIT**

To wrap all the consecutive `.group` elements together in a `.wrap` div:

The solution I came up with uses two loops and two arrays.

1. First is to find the "boundaries".
2. Second is to replace the consecutive `.group` elements with a div containing them.

See comments within code:

```js
    // Find the first and last of a serie of .group elements
    var isFirst = [];
    var isLast = [];

    // Loop thought all .item
    $(".item").each(function(){
      // Find a fist of a serie
      if (!$(this).prev().hasClass("group") && $(this).hasClass("group")) {
        console.log( "FIRST: " +$(this).text() );
        isFirst.push( $(this) );
      }
      // Find a last of a serie
      if (!$(this).next().hasClass("group") && $(this).hasClass("group")) {
        console.log( "LAST: " +$(this).text() );
        isLast.push( $(this).next() );  // Adding the next element, which IS NOT .group
      }
    });

    // Loop throug all the "first" element to replace them + all nextUntil by a wrapper element containing them all.
    isFirst.forEach(function(element, index){
      // Create the wrapper
      var wrapper = $("<div class='wrap'>");
      // Keep the previous in memory
      var previous = element.prev();
      // Append all elements until (not including) the one after the last.
      element.nextUntil(isLast[index]).addBack().each(function(){
        wrapper.append( $(this) )
      });
      // Append !
      previous.after(wrapper);
    });
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 5px dotted #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="item">Item 1</p>
<p class="item">Item 2</p>
<p class="item group">Item 3</p>
<p class="item group">Item 4</p>
<p class="item">Item 5</p>
<p class="item group">Item 6</p>
<p class="item group">Item 7</p>
<p class="item group">Item 8</p>
<p class="item">Item 9</p>
```

Run in full page mode ;)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xadJWe?editors=1111).

Comment: Thank you for the reply - addBack is something I had done at some point and given up on.   This is helpful and going in the right direction.   Note that the addBack now outlines/wraps ALL individual P tags - not the grouping of p tags grouped.  Run the run code snippet button.   Is there a way to select the group of p.group and wrap the multiple p.group?

Comment: `andSelf()` is also doing this... Run your own snippet ;) I will think about this and get back to you.

Comment: So here is a solution... Hoping that fits your needs.

Comment: You nailed it.  I like the way you've stepped through - learned a few new things and how to apply them.  Thank you so much for this awesome assist.